# How do i make a IFrame slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need a iframe slideshow that animates between a HTML iframe. I have 5 `iframe`s that have to automatically switch between themselves and loop.

How would I create a dynamic `iframe` slideshow?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [innerFade plugin](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/) for jQuery?
I've used it several times, it allows you to have a slideshow with almost anything, so I guess iframes will work!

Comment: what is the benefit compared to fadein and fadeout?

Comment: If you look at the plugin's page, you'll see that it removes the burden of applying the transition (fade in/out or whatever you want to use) between all your elements from you.
It'll take a reference to a container and automatically fade between all the container's children.